# How to get a longtable and a section on one page?

Tags: longtable

I have a name of the section followed by a longtable. The name of a section in on one page, the rest is empty and the table stars on the second page. How to deal with this, please?

Comment: Can you please provide minimal code? Thanks

Comment: Sadly, reliable psychics are in very short supply on this site. In fact, they may comprise the null set. Unless you show us some actual code -- preferably beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` -- that gives rise to the issue you wish to fix, odds that somebody will manage to guess correctly what you're doing, diagnose the situation, and propose a workable remedy are rather bleak.